# Usage of a word

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, usage

What is the right variant?

- there were 3.5 millions of people

or

- there was 3.5 million of people

Comment: singular, and no "of".  The same applies to "thousands" and "hundreds".

Comment: Neither. _There were 3.5 million people_ (no _of_).